# GetModuleFileNameEx fails

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that gets the name of the program that created an open window:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")


int main()
{
    system("color 1f");

    DWORD dwProcessId;
    DWORD dwThreadId ;

    while(1)
    {
        Sleep(2000);
        HWND hForg = GetForegroundWindow();
        dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hForg, &dwProcessId);
        //cout << "Thread Id: " << dwThreadId << endl;
        //cout << "Process Id: " << dwProcessId << endl;

        DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ;
        bool bInheritHandle = false;
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess,
                                      bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
        if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hProcess)
            cout << "Failed to open process!" << endl;
        HMODULE hMod = (HMODULE)GetWindowLongPtr(hForg, GWLP_HINSTANCE);
        if(!hMod)
            cout << "Null Module!" << endl;
        char szModFileName[MAX_PATH];

        GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, (HMODULE)hMod, szModFileName, MAX_PATH);
        char szWindowName[MAX_PATH];
        GetWindowText(hForg, szWindowName, MAX_PATH);
        cout << "Window Name: " << szWindowName << endl;
        cout << "Created by: " << szModFileName << endl << endl;
    }


        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

when I run the program it works but it never retrieves the name of the program but instead it retrieves the name of the visual c++ program???!!!
can anyone edit or help about my code. thnx in advance

Comment: Why does your code keep going as if nothing is wrong if the process or module handle is NULL?  Also, run this outside of Visual Studio if you aren't doing so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is defined as `-1`, while OpenProcess returns NULL if the function fails.  I don't know what `GetModuleFileNameEx` will do if given a NULL process handle, but if HMODULE is NULL the name of the current executable is returned so it might do that for other invalid input.

According to the MSDN documentation for `GetModuleFileNameEx`, the recommended way to get the name of the executable for a process is by calling `GetProcessImageFileName` and not `GetModuleFileNameEx`.  You'll have to resolve your issue with `OpenProcess` first.

Comment: thnx a lot "1201ProgramAlarm" it was great!! I used it and got what I want. another one last question: if I write cout << hProcess << endl; I see incrementing address values eg: 0x00000060 0x00000064... I think beacuase I forgot to close the handle hProcess. so if I don't close like in my case  does this mean "memory leak"? if so does OpenProcess() allocate memory on the heap??? thanx

Comment: @KokuVanish `OpenProcess` is a windows function, so it will allocate memory and other resource independent of your program.  What it returns is a handle (sorta like an index) to those resources that it is using.  You need to close the handle when you are done with it so those resource can be released.  If you don't it will eventually run out of resource handles and all sorts of weird stuff will start to happen.